# A way to dynamically add fields to struct in ruby

Tags: ruby, struct, metaprogramming

Lets say I have this struct with the fields: first_name, last_name, phone

```
Contact = Struct.new :first_name, :last_name, :phone
```

now i want to dynamically add another field named :email.

is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `OpenStruct` will be a better choice here?

Comment: Depending on your other needs you could even keep this data in simple `Hash`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby's [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) seems best fit for this use case.

```
require 'ostruct'
...
contact = OpenStruct.new(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", phone: "XXXXXXX")
```

And later you can do

```
contact.email = "john.doe@mymail.com"
```